# RegExp for Redis Auth Token on AWS

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation

Looking for regular expression to use in a cloudformation script with below rules:

- Must be only printable ASCII characters.
- Must be at least 16 characters and no more than 128 characters in length.
- Cannot contain any of the following characters: '/', '"', or '@'.

  `"AllowedPattern": "[0-9a-zA-Z\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\[\\\]\^\_\{\|\}\~].{16,128}$",`

Tried above but JSON doesnt seem to accept it. I believe some issue with `\`, as this `"AllowedPattern": "[0-9a-zA-Z].{16,128}$",` seems to work.  Any help ?

Comment: I think you should double escape the backslashes in the AllowedPattern to make it valid JSON syntax.

Comment: Note that you should remove `.` before the quantifier, or you will quantify the dot rather than what you want to allow. Also, add `^` at the start. There may be a problem with `-`, put it at the very end of the bracket expression, right before `]`. Note you do not need to escape many chars in this expression. Doubling the backslashes may really be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `.` before the quantifier, or you will quantify the dot rather than the character class with the chars you want to allow.

Also, add `^` at the start to make sure the length restriction is applied at all.

Also, you may avoid issues with escaping style if you write the character ranges in a special way. You can write the pattern as

```
"^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?\\[-_{-~]{16,128}$"
```

It will match 16 to 128 char strings that only contain

- `0-9` - digits
- `a-zA-Z` - ASCII letters
- `#-.` - `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`
- `:-?` - `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`
- `\[-_` - `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`
- `{-~` - `{`, `|`, `}`. `~`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c4Q1Wb/1).

Comment: This supposed to be for a Cloudformation template.  Some how `"AllowedPattern": "^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?[-_{-~]{16,128}$",` is not accepted by Cloudformation as a valid regular expression.

Comment: @Amogh That is rather strange. I suggest you try with very simple regex then, and see if a regex works at all. Try `".+"`, or `"[^ ]+"` first, and if you do not get any results, you are just using the regex incorrectly.

Comment: `".+"`,  `"[^ ]+"` both work fine, no error reported. This  `"^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?[-_{-~]{16,128}$",` throws Error: `Template contains errors.: Template error: Paramater 'RedisPassword' AllowedPattern must be a valid regular expression.`

Comment: Then, the pattern should be parsed with a regex engine that requires `[` to be escaped. Try `"^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?\[-_{-~]{16,128}$"` or `"^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?\\[-_{-~]{16,128}$"`

Comment: `"^[0-9a-zA-Z#-.:-?\\[-_{-~]{16,128}$"`  This one IT IS !!  May be update your answer for this and I will mark it as answered. Thanks a ton.